# which would be the most time efficient way to perform these nested loops?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        for k in range(z):
            if arr[i][j][k] != 0:
                arr[i][j][k] = 1
```

I'm traversing through a 3D array and if any value is not equal to 1, I would like to change it to 1.

Comment: What are x, y, and z? Are these the length of each dimension?

Comment: Yes , they refer to length of each dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `numpy`, just write:

```
arr[arr!=0] = 1
```

or if you only need a boolean array:

```
result = arr!=0
```

If you, on the other side, have a list of list of lists:

```
for plane in arr:
    for row in plane:
        row[:] = [int(item!=0) for item in row]
```